# Get values XML feed by name - PHP

Tags: php, xml, tags

I'm using XML to insert products into my db with PHP. I can access / read the xml feed with the following code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('testfeed.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $product) {
    $pname = $product->name;
    $pdescr = $product->description;
    echo $pname;
    echo $pdescr;
    }
```

Below is my example XML:

```
<product ID="9">
<name>Product X</name>
<properties>
<property name="categoryPath">
<value>path-to-category</value>
</property>
<property name="stock">
<value>1</value>
</property>
</properties>
</product>
```

It's easy to get the values for name, but how do I get the value of the categorypath, since this one is inside properties->property->value and declared in the `<property name="categoryPath">`?

Thanks!

Comment: can you change the name of the xml-tag "value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way without looping too much through the structures will be using XPath:

```
$values = $xml->xpath('//property[@name="categoryPath"]/value');
```

Just loop through the returned array and cast each result to string when needed, and you're done.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! What path would I need to set? Full path like: $xml->xpath('/products/product/properties/property[@name="categoryPath"]/value')?

Comment: depends on your xml structure. the one i wrote in the example will get you all property nodes having the name attribute with the given value, regardless of where they are in the structure. If, by defintion,  you are are able to provide a full absolute path, you should prefer that for performance reasons. third case would be the one where you have property nodes in different paths, but you don't need all. then use the full path as well.

Comment: Hi Jossif, thanks! If I use your example, I get output "Array". Am I missing something?

Comment: I just edited my first version of the solution. xpath() returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. You can loop through them. To get the actual value of each element, just cast to string or use the element within a string (since SimpleXMLElement has a magic __toString() method which does the casting for you).

Comment: Super! When looping through them via: foreach($pcat as $pcat2) {
        echo $pcat2;
    } I get the category path, thanks Jossif!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
While Jossif's answer is very good at getting all the nodes in bulk I'm including an edit for updated xml structure without using `xpath`:

```
$property = $product->properties->property;
$propertyAttribute = $property->attributes()->{'name'};

$catPath = ($propertyAttribute=="categoryPath")? $property->value : "value for missing paths";

print $catPath . PHP_EOL;
```

---

Since you don't seem to have any other similar xml nodes, you don't need the attribute to separate them.

You should be able to safely use this

```
$catPath = $product->properties->property->value;
print $catPath;
```

to get the string from the `value` node.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my limited xml example, but it has similar xml nodes, so there are more nodes with name "value"

Comment: can you post a better and broader sample xml then?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your help. I've added another node to the example, same structure with name "stock" added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('./testfeed.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $product) {
    $pname = $product->name;
    $pdescr = $product->properties->property["name"];
    $pdvalue = (string)$product->properties->property->value;
    echo "Prdo Name: $pname\n";
    echo "Prod Desc: $pdescr\n";
    echo "Prod Value: $pdvalue\n";

}
```

Output:

```
   Prdo Name: Product X
   Prod Desc: categoryPath
   Prod Value: path-to-category
```